# variance of restricted random vars

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d. with Bernoulli($p$). If we are interested only on a set of realizations of $X_1$ and $X_2$ denoted by $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, respectively, such that $Y_1+Y_2=S$, then what will be the variance of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ ?

Comment: Assume S is constant

Comment: If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are Bernoulli, then the set of realisations is either {0,0}, (0,1}, {1,0}, or {1,1}. The sum of those realisations must be one of {0, 1 or 2}. If the sum is 0, $Y_1$ must be zero and $Y_2$ must be zero. If the sum is 2, $Y_1$ must be 1 and $Y_2$ must be 1. So it seems to me that the only room for randomness is when the sum is 1, where $Y_1$ can be 0 or 1 etc

Comment: @wolfies yes, it is more interesting if S=1. If you generalize $X_1$ and $X_2$ as multinomial r.v.s with size 1 and equal probability $p$ for $k>2$ categories, then the problem provides more room for randomness.